# Add alternating row colors with column grouping colors-is it possible?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to style a GridView (in conjunction with jQuery's `tablesorter`) to have alternating row colors, but change the set of colors for each column grouping?  See image below:

[image: Example Image]

I'm currently hard-coding the cell background colors based on arrays I have created, e.g. greenArray is an integer array set to (0,1,2,3), purpleArray is (4,5,6,7) etc.  However, when I use the tablesorter plugin, obviously the cells keep their colors, which messes up the alternating color scheme:

[image]

**EDIT**: I'm currently adding background color in VB.NET.  The following function defines the arrays and then calls a ColorizeMe() function which actually applies the styling:

```
Private Sub StyleTable(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvReport.RowDataBound

            'Define arrays to color the gridview, if cell index is in array, it will be colored
            Dim blueArray() As Integer = {0, 17, 18, 19, 20}
            Dim greenArray() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4}
            Dim purpleArray() As Integer = {5, 6, 7, 8}
            Dim pinkArray() As Integer = {9, 10, 11, 12}
            Dim yellowArray() As Integer = {13, 14, 15, 16}

            _packworks.ColorizeMe(blueArray, greenArray, purpleArray, pinkArray, yellowArray, e.Row)

End Sub
```

And the ColorizeMe() function:

```
Public Sub ColorizeMe(ByVal blueArray() As Integer, ByVal greenArray() As Integer, _
                                 ByVal purpleArray() As Integer, ByVal pinkArray() As Integer, _
                                 ByVal yellowArray() As Integer, ByVal row As GridViewRow)
            Dim i As Integer = 0

            For Each cell As TableCell In row.Cells
                If Array.IndexOf(blueArray, i) <> -1 Then
                    If _isDark Then 'Color account column
                        cell.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#B0C4DE")
                    Else
                        cell.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E6E6FA")
                    End If
                ElseIf Array.IndexOf(greenArray, i) <> -1 Then
                    If _isDark Then
                        cell.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#a4d5a8")
                    Else
                        cell.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ddf5de")
                    End If
                ElseIf Array.IndexOf(purpleArray, i) <> -1 Then
                    If _isDark Then
                        cell.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ada4d4")
                    Else
                        cell.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#c7c6f4")
                    End If
                ElseIf Array.IndexOf(pinkArray, i) <> -1 Then
                    If _isDark Then
                        cell.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e3b3e0")
                    Else
                        cell.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#fae1fa")
                    End If
                ElseIf Array.IndexOf(yellowArray, i) <> -1 Then
                    If _isDark Then
                        cell.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e0e3ab")
                    Else
                        cell.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f5f8dd")
                    End If
                End If

                i += 1
            Next

            _isDark = Not _isDark
        End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of the applicable code? It is possible, but it'd be easier to see what you're working with now.

Comment: I wish I could post the fiddle.  I'm currently adding the color backgrounds in .NET on the server side, I was just curious if I could accomplish the same functionality in jQuery, having little knowledge of the language.  However, I did add my server side code to the description if that helps you gain insight into my thinking.  I have several pages with varying columns that need to be colored, so I decided those arrays were the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your rows are alternating light/dark, you could take advantage of an alpha transparent background color:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/6rgab657

```
<table>
  <colgroup class="a" span="4" />
  <colgroup class="b" span="4" />
  <colgroup class="c" span="4" />
  <colgroup class="d" span="4" />

  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
  background: blue;
}

.b {
  background: green;
}

.c {
  background: purple;
}

.d {
  background: red;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .70);
}
```

Comment: I'm beginning to implement this.  Keep in mind that this is .NET.  I've added an `ItemStyle-CssClass` attribute for each of my `TemplateFields` and set the CSS class to blue, green, etc, which works well.  However, the CSS is not picking up the `tr:nth-child(odd)` attribute.  I wonder if it is not able to override the manual classes I've set on the `TemplateFields`

Comment: It depends on how the colors are applied.  If it is via `style="background: red"`, then it is very difficult to overwrite and it would be best to remove it if you can.  If it is just with a class, you can adjust the selector to `tr:nth-child(odd) td` to make it more specific.