# How to target the <td>'s that falls under <th> with a colspan?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a dynamic table that generally look like this

```
----------------------------------------------------
|       AA        |      BB     |       CC        |
----------------------------------------------------
| X1 |  X2  | X3  |  Y1  |  Y2  |  Z1  | Z2  | Z3 |
----------------------------------------------------
| xx |  xx  | xx  |  yy  |  yy  |  zz  | zz  | zz |
---------------------------------------------------- 
| xx |  xx  | xx  |  yy  |  yy  |  zz  | zz  | zz |
----------------------------------------------------
```

And I want to have different colors for AA, BB, CC, etc -  generally alternate color (zebra stripes). 
I don't want to target just the AA cell, but the all the columns that fall under AA cell. All the `<td>`s under it.

I can't target using the the :nth-child(odd) because it will select the odd child columns instead of the odd column of `<th>` elements, and its childs.

Note that the number of child columns is not fixed. it can be one, two, three or more.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: Not with a pure CSS selector because it involves semantics that simply aren't reflected with the ones we currently have. See http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#table-pseudos where a new set of selectors has been proposed to address this - particularly the column combinator.

Comment: If pure CSS is not possible, I can go with JS

Comment: Possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280703/add-alternating-row-colors-with-column-grouping-colors-is-it-possible

Comment: @cimmanon colgroup seems to work. but seems like an extra overhead to to have the span number for the col span attribute. hm

Answer (score 1):

I see two CSS option to have something fluid.

1) (clumsy and tricky) for just a color , you may repeat a box-shadow under th. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ysLvE

```
th:nth-child(even) {
  background:yellow;
  box-shadow:
    0 1em  0  yellow,
    0 3em  0  yellow,
 /* and so on as much as needed , here Sass or alike is your friend */
    0 29em 0  yellow
}
```

here a Sass/scss version : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xqALu

2) (a bit smarter) you may insert a pseudo element with a background-image http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgCJp

```
th:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:3000px;/* what you think long enough */
  margin-bottom:-3000px; /* negative margin to reduce height virtually to zero */
  background:yellow url(http://lorempixel.com/600/800/nature/1) center;
}
```

If these approach do not suit your way of using CSS , javascript will then, be your savior :).
++

Comment: This is pretty neat. I like the second approach. The only thing I need to consider is the height. The height is not always the same - can be super short or super tall. But I guess there should be a way to make the height always 100% or something like that. I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with pure css, although requires css3 and it is not really beautiful:

```
TABLE > TH > TD:nth-child(1),
TABLE > TR > TD:nth-child(1),
TABLE > TR > TD:nth-child(2),
TABLE > TR > TD:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Second, third, columns go the same way.

It can be a little bit better if you can give the needed td-s a common class name (f.e. "redColumn" and "greenColumn"). In this case a simple

```
.redColumn {
    background-color: red;
}

.greenColumn {
    background-color: green;
}
```

will be ok.

Comment: I don't think it's going to work because technically td is not really "inside" the th/tr in terms of html code. So i don't think the target will be correct. As for the common class name, can't really do that because as mentioned in the questions, number of column is not fixed. Everything is dynamically created.